# Как отлавливать TimeoutError в asyncio

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, aiogram, asyncio

Подскажите пожалуйста как отлавливать TimeoutError.
Я запускаю телеграмм бота он работает все в порядке, потом при потере интернет соединения
`asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError`.

Вопрос в следующем, как избежать данной ошибки? То есть я хочу чтобы после того как соединение вновь появлялось, бот запускался самостоятельно после восстановления соединения.

Код:

```
from aiogram import Bot
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage

storage = MemoryStorage()

TOKEN = open('token.txt', 'r').readline()    
bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)

async def on_startup(_):
    print('Бот запущен!')


def main():
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True, on_startup=on_startup)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        main()
    except Exception as e:
        print('Произошла ошибка!')
```

Comment: Ну а код для слабаков, как я понимаю?

Comment: Код стандартный , для запуска на aiogram. Подумал он не нужен для объяснения. Сейчас прикреплю.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос полный стек с ошибкой (кнопка [edit]). Просто, мне казалось он и так зациклен. Если нет, то можно зациклить код с main() и ловить в нем ошибку, тогда если бот упадет он тут же поднимется

Comment: @gil9red Хорошо, когда снова упадёт прикреплю стек.

Comment: Бот не должен падать, если вы действительно этот код запускаете, в логике aiogram это уже предусмотрено

Comment: Нашел примерную проблему, она заключается в не стабильном интернет соединении , то есть бывают моменты , когда интернет пропал, потом появился, но так уже висит TimeoutError и бот не работает.

Comment: Добавил корректировки в вопрос.

Comment: стектрейс нужен

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA А можно подробнее ?

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду трассировку?

Comment: @ZhymabekRoman, согласен. У меня по крайней мере бот не падал. Продолжал дальше работать. Как вариант убрать блок try-except, и запустить без него.

Answer (score 1):

Вешаете декоратор `@TimeoutErrorHandler` над проблемной функцией и наслаждаетесь логами о перехваченной ошибке.
Этот декоратор просто вызывает функцию, над которой его повесели, в бесконечном цикле, при `TimeoutError` он ждет 1 секунду и снова запускает функцию. Если вдруг вылезет другая ошибка, то ей ничего не помешает.

```py
from asyncio.exceptions import TimeoutError
from time import sleep

def TimeoutErrorHandler(func):
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        while True:
            try:
                func(*args, **kwargs)
            except TimeoutError:
                print(f'TimeoutError excepted, wait 1 second')
                sleep(1)
    return wrap

@TimeoutErrorHandler
def func_with_error():
    raise TimeoutError

func_with_error()
```

Логи будут выглядеть примерно так:

```
TimeoutError excepted, wait 1 second
TimeoutError excepted, wait 1 second
...
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, я правильно понимаю что `func_with_error()` это пример функции? То есть в конце функции можно повесить `raise TimeoutError` и это будет отображать логи? То есть по сути я вешаю декоратор, он уже будет отлавливать ошибку и потом если будет срабатывание он перезапустит функцию?

Comment: @Alex, грубо говоря да. только загвоздка в том, что функция не продолжит работу, а перезапустится.